# Making a simple word game can anyone help me make it more efficient?(Python)

Tags: python

This is a function which pulls a random word out of a .txt file then fills some of the letters with underscores can anyone make this more efficient? Thank you

```
import random
def randomword():
  word = random.choice(open('words.txt').readlines())
  length = len(word)-1
  random1=random.randint(0,len(word)-2)
  random2=random.randint(0,len(word)-2)
  listword=list(word)
  listword[random1]="_"
  listword[random2]="_"
  newword="".join(listword)
  print (newword)
word()
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't actually run (I assume `word()` was supposed to be `randomword()`). There is a separate site for reviewing [working code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) so asking for improvement would be off-topic here. However, I would spend some time getting to grips with Python in general before worrying about efficiency; a lot of the efficiency will come from just exploring the language and becoming more familiar. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import random
def randomword(words):
    word = random.choice(words)
    return ''.join( [ c if i not in random.sample(list(range(len(word))), random.randint(1,5)) else '_' for i,c in enumerate(word)] )
```

And adjust the `randint(1,5)` to reflect the minimum and maximum number of substituted values you want.

If you are calling this function several times I would also suggest reading the list of words only once, and passing it to the function as an argument (or even using it as a global variable).